# Use poly() in R formula to predict

Tags: r, function, formula, predict

I have a question about the formula and the user defined function:

#### Case 1:

```
 clotting <- data.frame(
     u = c(5,10,15,20,30,40,60,80,100),
     lot1 = c(118,58,42,35,27,25,21,19,18),
     lot2 = c(69,35,26,21,18,16,13,12,12))

 g1 = glm(lot1 ~ log(u) + poly(u,1), data = clotting, family = Gamma)
 dc = clotting
 dc$u = 1
 predict(g1, dc)

      1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9
 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929
```

However, if I just simply wrap the poly as a user defined function ( in reality I would have my own more complex function)  then I will get error:

#### Case 2:

```
 xpoly <- function(x, degree=1){poly(x,degree)}
 g2 = glm(lot1 ~ log(u) + xpoly(u,1), data = clotting, family = Gamma)
 predict(g2, dc)
       Error in poly(x, degree) :
      'degree' must be less than number of unique points
```

It seems that the predict treats the user defined function in the formula with I().  My question is how can I get the  results for Case2 same as case1?

Anyone can have any idea about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`poly` is a bit of a unique function here. By default, it returns a set of orthogonal polynomials so it's doing some centering and rescaling of the data. If you want to be able to predict using the coefficients from the fitted model, you would need to transform new data in the same way that was done with the original data. This means some additional data must be passed along.

First I will point out that if you use the raw, non-orthogonal values, you would not experience this problem.

```
g1 <- glm(lot1 ~ log(u) + poly(u,1, raw=T), data = clotting, family = Gamma)
xpoly<-function(x,degree=1){poly(x,degree, raw=T)}
g2 <- glm(lot1 ~ log(u) + xpoly(u,1), data = clotting, family = Gamma)

dc=clotting
dc$u=1
predict(g1,dc)
#       1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9 
#-0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 
predict(g2,dc)
#       1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9 
#-0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929
```

But let's further explore how `poly` passing along the scaling information to `predict`. The work actually happens in the `model.frame` function. Compare these two results

```
attr(terms(model.frame(lot1 ~ log(u) + poly(u,1), clotting)), "predvar")
# list(lot1, log(u), poly(u, 1, coefs = list(alpha = 40, norm2 = c(1, 
9, 8850))))
attr(terms(model.frame(lot1 ~ log(u) + xpoly(u,1), clotting)), "predvar")
# list(lot1, log(u), xpoly(u, 1))
```

You can see that the call to `poly()` in the first formula has been adjusted in the `predvar` attribute of the formula that's returned. This done in the `model.frame` code

```
...
if (is.null(attr(formula, "predvars"))) {
    for (i in seq_along(varnames)) predvars[[i + 1L]] <- makepredictcall(variables[[i]], 
        vars[[i + 1L]])
    attr(formula, "predvars") <- predvars
}
...
```

Note that it calls the `makepredictcall()` function which is a generic function which dispatches based on the class of the returned object. It happens that `poly` returns an object of class "poly"

```
class(poly(1:5, 1))
# [1] "poly"   "matrix"
```

So what get's called for the "poly" data is this function

```
stats:::makepredictcall.poly
function (var, call) 
{
    if (as.character(call)[1L] != "poly") 
        return(call)
    call$coefs <- attr(var, "coefs")
    call
}
<bytecode: 0x123262178>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

This is where the `coef=` attributes are added. But also note that it checks that the call was from the "poly" function itself. Since your function is named "xpoly" but returns a "poly" object, the coefficient information isn't returned. One workaround would be to change the return class of your object and create your own `makepredictcall` function. For example you could do

```
xpoly <- function(...){p<-poly(...); class(p)[1]<-"xpoly"; p}
makepredictcall.xpoly <- function(var, call) {
    call$coefs <- attr(var, "coefs")
    call
}
```

Note that this new version of `xpoly` will also accept the `coef=` argument and pass it along to `poly()` via the `...` parameters. Then you can run

```
g1 <- glm(lot1 ~ log(u) + poly(u,1), data = clotting, family = Gamma)
g2 <- glm(lot1 ~ log(u) + xpoly(u,1), data = clotting, family = Gamma)
predict(g1,dc)
#          1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9 
#-0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929
predict(g2,dc)
#          1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9 
#-0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929 -0.01398929
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed worked through. I got my problem solved through the R-help. The solution is exactly as you suggested:  write makepredcitcall for my own function. Thanks.