# Why does lm() with the subset argument give a different answer than subsetting in advance?

Tags: r, lm, poly

I am using `lm()` on a training set of data that includes a polynomial.  When I subset in advance with `[ ]` I get different coefficients compared to using the `subset` argument in the `lm()` function call.  Why?

```r
library(ISLR2)

set.seed (1)
train <- sample(392, 196)

auto_train <- Auto[train,]


lm.fit.data <- lm(mpg ~ poly(horsepower, 2), data = auto_train)
summary(lm.fit.data)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ poly(horsepower, 2), data = auto_train)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -12.8711  -2.6655  -0.0096   2.0806  16.1063 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)           23.8745     0.3171  75.298  < 2e-16 ***
#> poly(horsepower, 2)1 -89.3337     4.4389 -20.125  < 2e-16 ***
#> poly(horsepower, 2)2  33.2985     4.4389   7.501 2.25e-12 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 4.439 on 193 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.705,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.702 
#> F-statistic: 230.6 on 2 and 193 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16


lm.fit.subset <- lm(mpg ~ poly(horsepower, 2), data = Auto, subset = train)
summary(lm.fit.subset)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ poly(horsepower, 2), data = Auto, subset = train)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -12.8711  -2.6655  -0.0096   2.0806  16.1063 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)            23.5496     0.3175  74.182  < 2e-16 ***
#> poly(horsepower, 2)1 -123.5881     6.4587 -19.135  < 2e-16 ***
#> poly(horsepower, 2)2   47.7189     6.3613   7.501 2.25e-12 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 4.439 on 193 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.705,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.702 
#> F-statistic: 230.6 on 2 and 193 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: the vector passed to `poly` is not being filtered by `subset` for some reason, run `debugonce(poly); lm(mpg ~ poly(horsepower, 2), data = Auto, subset = train)` and check `length(x)`, it is the same as `nrow(Auto)` instead of `length(train)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** As suggested in other comments and answers, the characteristics of the orthogonal polynomial basis are computed *before* the subsetting is taken into account.

To add more technical detail to @JonManes's answer, let's look at [lines 545-553 of the R code where 'model.frame' is defined](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/models.R#L545-L553).

First we have (lines 545-549)

```r
 if(is.null(attr(formula, "predvars"))) {
        for (i in seq_along(varnames))
            predvars[[i+1L]] <- makepredictcall(variables[[i]], vars[[i+1L]])
        attr(formula, "predvars") <- predvars
    }
```

- At this point in the code, `formula` will not be an actual formula (that would be too easy!), but rather a `terms` object that contains various useful-to-developers info about model structures ...
- `predvars` is the attribute that defines the information needed to properly reconstruct data-dependent bases like orthogonal polynomials and splines (see `?makepredictcall` for a *little* bit more information, or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463677/use-poly-in-r-formula-to-predict), although in general this stuff is really poorly documented; I'd expect it to be documented [here](https://developer.r-project.org/model-fitting-functions.html) but it isn't ...). For example,

```r
attr(terms(model.frame(mpg ~ poly(horsepower, 2), data = auto_train)),  "predvars")
```

gives

```r
list(mpg, poly(horsepower, 2, coefs = list(alpha = c(102.612244897959, 
142.498828460405), norm2 = c(1, 196, 277254.530612245, 625100662.205702
))))
```

These are the coefficients for the polynomial, *which depend on the distribution of the input data*.

Only **after** this information has been established, on line 553, do we get

```r
subset <- eval(substitute(subset), data, env)
```

In other words, the subsetting argument doesn't even get evaluated until after the polynomial characteristics are determined (all of this information is then passed to the internal `C_modelframe` function, which you *really* don't want to look at ...)

Note that this issue does **not** result in an information leak between training and testing sets in a statistical learning context: the parameterization of the polynomial doesn't affect the predictions of the model at all (in theory, although as usual with floating point the results are unlikely to be exactly identical). At worst (if the training and full sets were very different) it could reduce numerical stability a bit.

FWIW this is all surprising (to me) and seems worth raising on the `r-devel@r-project.org` mailing list (at least a note in the documentation seems in order).

Comment: Thank you Ben.  Is there a scenario where it makes sense to figure out the polynomial characteristics before doing the subsetting.  This seems like a case of "leaking" information between a training and testing dataset.  Does that concern make sense?

Comment: I'm not worried about leaking; the parameterization of the polynomial doesn't affect the *predictions* of the model at all in theory, although as usual with floating point the results are unlikely to be exactly identical.  At worst (if the training and full sets were very different) it could reduce numerical stability a bit.  My concern with the way it's implemented in R, which seems illogical and confusing [as you found out]. According to `git blame` it's been this way more or less forever (hard to do the archaeology farther than 18 years back ...)

Comment: Thanks again.  I sent a note to r-devel.  If you ever make it to Miami lunch is on me.

Answer (score 2):

In your second call it looks like `poly()` is computed first before subsetting. Compare the outputs of `model.frame()` below:

```r
# first call
model.frame(mpg ~ poly(horsepower, 2), data = auto_train)[1:5,]
#>      mpg poly(horsepower, 2).1 poly(horsepower, 2).2
#> 326 44.3         -0.1037171808          0.1498371034
#> 169 23.0         -0.0372467155         -0.0099055358
#> 131 26.0         -0.0429441840         -0.0000530004
#> 301 23.9         -0.0239526225         -0.0300950106
#> 272 23.2          0.0045347198         -0.0601592336

# second call
model.frame(mpg ~ poly(horsepower, 2), data = Auto, subset = train)[1:5,]
#>      mpg poly(horsepower, 2).1 poly(horsepower, 2).2
#> 326 44.3         -0.0741931315          0.1133792778
#> 169 23.0         -0.0282078693         -0.0034299423
#> 131 26.0         -0.0321494632          0.0039029222
#> 301 23.9         -0.0190108168         -0.0185862638
#> 272 23.2          0.0006971527         -0.0418538153

# same as
model.frame(mpg ~ poly(horsepower, 2), data = Auto)[train,][1:5,]
#>      mpg poly(horsepower, 2).1 poly(horsepower, 2).2
#> 326 44.3         -0.0741931315          0.1133792778
#> 169 23.0         -0.0282078693         -0.0034299423
#> 131 26.0         -0.0321494632          0.0039029222
#> 301 23.9         -0.0190108168         -0.0185862638
#> 272 23.2          0.0006971527         -0.0418538153
```